# Time Complexity of removeVertex should be O(E1*E2)

Tags: data-structures, graph, hashmap

Time Complexity of removeVertex should be O(E1*E2), where "E1 represents the edges of the vertex to be removed(say V)" & '"E2 represents the edges of a particular edge(which is also a vertex in the adjacency list) of E1" while interating all elements of E1(which results in O(E1)), in order to call removeEdge(which itself is O(E2) for that particular element of E1.'

Is this statement correct or there is some misunderstanding for me?

If I'm correct, then why is the time complexity of remove Vertex said to be O(E),i.e., linear, instead of O(E1*E2) ?

My Code Implementation :-

```
removeEdge(vertex1,vertex2){
   this.adjacencyList[vertex2] = this.adjacencyList[vertex2].filter(v=>v!==vertex1)
}

removeVertex(vertex){
   while(this.adjacencyList[vertex].length){
      const adjacentVertex = this.adjacencyList[vertex].pop()
      this.removeEdge(vertex,adjacentVertex)
}
}
```

Expected Time Complexity : O(E1*E2)

Original Time Complexity : O(E)

Note : I'm using hashmap as the adjacency list.

Answer (thanks to @harold) : E1*E2 <= E, where E is the total number of edges, so as a result in worst case scenario, time complexity should be O(E).

Comment: Can you explain your E2 again, I don't really get that whole "edges of edge of the edges" thing

Comment: Ok @harold, let me reframe this : "E2 represents the edges of a particular edge(which is also a vertex in the adjacency list) of E1" while interating all elements of E1(which results in O(E1)), in order to call removeEdge(which itself is O(E2) for that particular element of E1. Please do let me know if I need to explain with the code that I've implemented if this is unclear to you.

Comment: *"the edges of the particular edge of the edges"*: sorry, you lost me.

Comment: Edges don't have edges, so "edge(s) of the edge(s)" is meaningless. Vertices are connected by edges, and edges are connected by vertices. It would be meaningful to express the task in these terms.

Comment: Is your graph directed or undirected? What is "interacting"?

Comment: @KartikSaini sure, let's see the code.

Comment: @trincot , "E2 represents the edges of a particular edge(which is also a vertex in the adjacency list) of E1"

Comment: @trincot , sorry it's "iterating". In my implementation, I've used undirected graph implementation but that doesn't matter in either case i guess?

Comment: @harold ,  I've updated the question with my code implementation now. I hope you understand the meaning of E2 now. From my understanding now, the time complexity of removeVertex() would be O(E1*E2) right?
If yes, then why is the time complexity of remove Vertex said to be O(E),i.e., linear, and not O(E1*E2) ?

Comment: I still don't know what E2 is, but filtering all adjacency lists can be done in O(E) where E is the total number of edges in the graph (equivalently, O(V²)). If you have a hashmap of hashsets then you can remove vertex1 from the adjacency list of vertex2 in constant time.

Comment: Sorry, but "E2 represents the edges of a particular edge" is meaningless. An edge doesn't  *have* edges. Please use language that is common in graph theory.

Comment: Whether your graph is directed or not could make a difference in terms of time complexity.

Comment: The code you added is wrong. The value of the `while` condition will never change by the loop's body. Moreover, a hashmap doesn't have a `length` property. And why do you have `this.adjacentVertex[vertex]`? Looks like you intended `this.adjacencyList[vertex]`... Is this code even compiling?

Comment: @tricot , I've updated the code, I hope it clarifies my question now.

Comment: @tricot , Could you please explain how could it possibly affect time complexity of removeVertex by changing from undirected to directed or vice versa?

Comment: @harold , thank you so much for this clarification. That cleared my doubt as E1*E2<=E, where E is the total number of edges, so as a result in worst case, time complexity should be O(E). I've updated the question with the solution itself now.